# SwiftUI iOS 16 MapKit Globe

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit

How do you configure the map to be zoomed out till globe is shown (swift)?  I know you can set the mapType to hybridFlyover or satelliteFlyover however this solution doesn't look like apple's map, when fully zoomed out.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Having trouble finding much online.

Answer (score 3):

Using SwiftUI on iOS 17:

```
.mapStyle(.imagery(elevation: .realistic))
```

or

```
.mapStyle(.hybrid(elevation: .realistic))
```

or

```
.mapStyle(.standard(elevation: .realistic))
```

note that **`.standard`** is not working, I think it's due to a bug, but it's working fine with other styles.